# Sequence of projected operators applied to sequence of vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, projection

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space over $\mathbb R$, $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a complete orthonormal system in $H$ and $P^{(n)}$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $H^{(n)} := {\rm span}(h_1,\dots,h_n)$.
>
> Further, let $A\colon H\to H$ be a bounded linear operator that is symmetric positive semi-definite and trace-class and let $A^{(n)} = P^{(n)} A P^{(n)}$.
>
> Finally, let $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a (possibly unbounded) sequence of vectors with $v_n\in H^{(n)}$ such that $\|A^{(n)} v_n\|\le M$ is bounded by some constant $M>0$ (in fact, it converges to some element $w\in H$).
>
> I need to show that $A v_n$ is also bounded by some (possibly different) constant $\tilde M>0$:  $\|A v_n\|\le \tilde M$.

I have been struggling to prove this (and also to find counterexamples), but so far I cannot find the right analytical tools.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
(This is not a homework exercise.)

**My attempts so far:**

Let $(e_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ be an (orthonormal) eigenbasis of $A$: $A = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \lambda_m\,  e_m\otimes e_m$, where $\lambda_m\in\mathbb R$. Then
$$
A = \sum_{k,l=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \lambda_m\, \langle h_k, e_m\rangle \, \langle e_m, h_l\rangle}_{=: a_{kl}} \, h_k\otimes h_l
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
A^{(n)} = \sum_{k,l=1}^{n} a_{kl} \, h_k\otimes h_l
$$
and therefore we obtain for $v_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \langle v_n, h_j\rangle h_j$:
$$
Av_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} \, \langle v_n, h_j\rangle\bigg) h_k
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
A^{(n)}v_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} \, \langle v_n, h_j\rangle\bigg) h_k
$$
Therefore
$$
\|Av_n\|^2 = \|A^{(n)}v_n\|^2 + \sum_{k >n} \bigg|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj} \, \langle v_n, h_j\rangle\bigg|^2
$$
and I somehow need to bound the right term. The $a_{kj}$ are probably decaying at some rate, but I don't see how to go on.

Comment: Trace-class operators are Hilbert-Schmidt, so $\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2 <\infty$.

Comment: How does $w$ come into this? Does $A^{(n)}v_n \to w$?

Comment: Yes, $A^{(n)} v_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} w$.